# How to parse byte data received from BLE device in android

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have beacons connected to my android device. For this, I am reading the value of 17 bytes and those 17 bytes represent specific data such as humidity, temperature etc. So do I  parse them and make them in their standard format.
[image: The format for data to be recieved]